# my libgdx timer updates the intervals too quickly

Tags: java, timer, libgdx

my libgdx timer is meant to pump produce a random number every second but when i put the timer in the render method it updates much quicker than once a second and i dont know how to fix this.Also in my game the bush is suppose to rustle before the enemy shoots but it all seems to happen at once.

```
    timer.scheduleTask( new Task(){ public void run(){
    rando =rn.nextInt(8);
    Gdx.app.log("the num is", Integer.toString(rando));
    if(rando == 0){
        bush.rustle();
        bush2.rustle2();
        bush3.dontrustle3();
        bush4.dontrustle4();
        enemy.shoot();
        enemy2.shoot();
        enemy3.godown();
        enemy4.godown();


    }
     if(rando == 1){
        bush.dontrustle();
        bush2.rustle2();
        bush3.rustle3();
        bush4.dontrustle4();
        enemy.godown();
        enemy2.shoot();
        enemy3.shoot();
        enemy4.godown();

    }
    if(rando == 2){
        bush.rustle();
        bush2.dontrustle2();
        bush3.rustle3();
        bush4.rustle4();
        enemy2.godown();
        enemy.shoot();
        enemy4.shoot();
        enemy3.shoot();


    }

    if(rando == 3){
        bush.rustle();
        bush2.rustle2();
        bush3.rustle3();
        bush4.rustle4();
        enemy.shoot();
        enemy2.goup();
        enemy4.goup();
        enemy3.shoot();

    }

    if(rando == 4){
        bush.rustle();
        bush2.rustle2();
        bush3.rustle3();
        bush4.rustle4();
        enemy2.godown();
        enemy.godown();
        enemy4.shoot();
        enemy3.shoot();


    }

    if(rando == 5){
        bush.rustle();
        bush2.rustle2();
        bush3.rustle3();
        bush4.rustle4();
        enemy2.godown();
        enemy.shoot();
        enemy4.godown();
        enemy3.shoot();


    }

    if(rando == 6){
        bush.rustle();
        bush2.rustle2();
        bush3.rustle3();
        bush4.rustle4();
        enemy2.godown();
        enemy.goup();
        enemy4.godown();
        enemy3.godown();


    }

    if(rando == 7){
        bush.rustle();
        bush2.rustle2();
        bush3.rustle3();
        bush4.rustle4();
        enemy2.shoot();
        enemy.goup();
        enemy4.shoot();
        enemy3.shoot();


    }




    }}, 1,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

your random is called around 60 times per second. same as your fps. 
Here is a simple trick. In your render make a counter and increment it. when counter%60==0 then produce a random number

```
 public void render(float deltaTime)
  {
   counter++;
   if(counter%60==0) // if u need more precision mode it by your fps
    {
     get a random number
     counter=0;
    }
   // code for render 
  }
```

hope this helps

Comment: just made an edit forgot to put ==0 in the if condition

Comment: when i put it in the create method though i cant manipulate intervals

Comment: because create method will called only once in the game  while render is called 60 times(or ur fps) a second

Comment: i understand that but i need a solution to the problem i want to manipulate the intervals

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but is this code in your render loop? If so, you are creating a new task every frame, so you are seeing many tasks execute in quick succession.

Instead, you should call `scheduleTask` only once (in `create` or in response to a button press or something).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for you as a information that I suggest for easy timing.

I'm fighting a lot with timers in my current project.. The easiest way for me to accomplish timer things is the following.

```
float 1second = 1000
float theEndTime = TimeUtils.millis() + 1second
```

and later than to Check whether the time is reached:

```
if(TimeUtils.millis() - theEndTime > 0){
    //do cool stuff, like shoot and reset the Timer, so it just shoots once
    //example:
    generateRandomNumber(); //now wait another second!
    theEndTime = TimeUtils.millis() + 1second //that simple??
}
```

As you can see you have millisecond controll about your actions..

You can generate with this really complex Timers, every one firin off another, through a process, as long as you wish, and not getting confused with anything.

Hope that helps!